# How to make a content a website dynamic in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Below is my html code with two different sections that I am not being able to make them dynamic in wordpress.

```
<section class="contact">
        <h1>how it works</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, molestias facere nam esse voluptatum cupiditate recusandae deleniti neque quidem! Expedita necessitatibus saepe tempore corporis magnam ut impedit ea tempora quae.Select the products you wish to order. request a quote, fill out all the required fields and upload your artwork. Zazzoo will be in contact with you withing 24 hours to confirm your order.</p>
        <div class="button">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Contact us</button>
        </div>
    </section><!-- end of contact section  -->
    <section class="opportunity">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 ideas">
                <h2>turn your ideas into reality</h2>
                <hr/><p>weretrerum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor laudantium porro natus quo, sit ex nemo, nostrum pariatur ipsum, hic, officiis facilis enim debitis? Doloremque sequi sed ex quae, eaque.</p>
            </div>                  
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 opportunitycolumn">
                <h2>opportunity</h2>
                <hr>
                <br/>
                <h3>Are you a designer?</h3>
                <p>Send us your work and we will manage your print...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

How can I convert the code above into wordpress so that consequently it becomes dynamic?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your question is. Please can you simplify?

Comment: @Gavin Thomas. Sure...Just editted the question and hope it makes more sense. Thanks

Comment: <?php the_title() ?>
<?php the_content() ?>

Comment: Can you clarify what it is that you mean by _dynamic_...?

Comment: By saying dynamic I meant content that can be edited in wordpress.
@NooBskie. Inside h1 I put <?php the_title() ?> and replaced the paragraph by <?php the_content() ?>. 
I also create a new post in the backend name HOW IT WORKS>
The problem is that when I load the page, it picked up any random post that I have and not the one named HOW IT WORKS.
How can I do especifically display that post?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example of a basic loop in WordPress that picks the most recent article from a category:

```
<?php $get_posts = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => 21 ) ); // "'cat' => 21" replace with whichever category your post is in
while($get_posts->have_posts()) : $get_posts->the_post(); ?>
<section class="contact">
  <div>

  <?php The_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>

  <div>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  </div>

</div>
</section>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>
```

`<?php The_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>` Isnt needed in your case but this is where the featured image is set as well.

You can do many things with loops to customize it the way you need

[Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) is a reference that goes more in depth about loops.

If you do not want to put the post in a category you could also call it specifically by its id via the following (not tested) [Reference](https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/query-or-show-a-specific-post-in-wordpress-php-code-example-44)

```
<?php
  $post_id = 1; //changeme
  $queried_post = get_post($post_id);
  $title = $queried_post->post_title;
  echo $title;
  echo $queried_post->post_content;
?>
```